# Unable to create tap device vnet d: Operation not permitted

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt, centos6.5

I am trying to add a bridge network to my guest VM on a Centos 6 host.
I have created a bridge br0 by adding a file:

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0:

```
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
STP=on
ONBOOT=yes
```

Also, I have added a line in my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:

```
BRIDGE=br0
```

Now, I tried to create a VM using:

```
virt-install -n ubuntu_vm --disk path=kvm-images/ubuntu-12.04.qcow2,size=30,format=qcow2 --ram=2048 --cdrom= --os-type=linux --network bridge=br0 --os-variant=ubuntuprecise --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0
```

Now, I am getting the following error:

```
Starting install...
**ERROR    Unable to create tap device vnet%d: Operation not permitted**
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///session start ubuntu_new_vm
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

I see that this problem was fixed before libvirt 0.10.2 which I am using currently, but still I am getting the same error.

http://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2012-May/msg00678.html

Answer (score 0):

From the error message I see that you are running virt-install as an unprivileged user connecting to qemu:///session. With the unprivileged libvirtd instance you are very limited in what networking modes you can use, and in partuclar the 'network' mode is not available as your user won't have privileges to manage the TAP devices.

The alternatives are you use the privileged libvirtd instance (qemu:///system) to run the VM, which gives it full network access, or enable the QEMU setuid network helper. This lets you use --network bridge=NAME for virt-install when running unprivileged, delegating TAP device setup to the setuid helper program